# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i'm trying to use the HBase shell. To do that i just launch the command `list`.
When i do that it appears this:

> ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: null

None of the previous answers to this question work for me.
I usually use HBase locally on my computer and i've nevere creates any cluster with hadoop.
ps. when i launch `jps` i can't see any processe which indicates that HBase is running.
Anyone know what could be wrong ?
Two days ago everything was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have completed [this](https://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html) installations aleast and have Hbase configured.

Error you getting is because Hmaster is not running. you will have to start Hmaster.

```
bin/start-hbase.sh
```

Comment: Of course, i did it. But it still doesn't work. I don't think that's the problem.